# Commerce - added options/attributes for some products within a product type

Tags: commerce

I am developing a restaurant / takeaway site with e-commerce functionality.

I have figured out how to do such things as adding extras to a product such as extra cheese or extra pepperoni. My only issue is that I have some dishes/products within a product type that offer an option of salad or chips, or salad, rice or chips.

I have tried using the [Commerce Product add-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) module which attaches a product type onto another product type but the issue with this is that it only allows for checkboxes or a list where more than one option can be selected OR none at all.

I need that the customer must pick an option.

Can anyone with good commerce knowledge help me out here or point me in the right direction at the least as I am stuck for options.

Thanks.